# curl halts script execution

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

my script uses curl to upload images to [smugsmug](http://www.smugsmug.com/) site via [smugsmug api](http://wiki.smugmug.net/display/API/show+1.2.2?method=smugmug.images.upload).
i loop through a folder and upload every image in there. but after 3-4 uploads, curl_exec would fail, stopped everything and prevent other images from uploading.

```
$upload_array = array(
    "method" => "smugmug.images.upload",
    "SessionID" => $session_id,
    "AlbumID" => $alb_id,
    "FileName" => zerofill($n, 3) . ".jpg",
    "Data" => base64_encode($data),
    "ByteCount" => strlen($data),
    "MD5Sum" => $data_md5);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $upload_array);
curl_setopt(
    $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
    "https://upload.smugmug.com/services/api/rest/1.2.2/");
$upload_result = curl_exec($ch); //fails here
curl_close($ch);
```

updated:
so i added logging into my script. when it does fail, the logging stops after **fwrite($fh, "begin curl\n");**

```
fwrite($fh, "begin curl\n");
$upload_result = curl_exec($ch);
fwrite($fh, "curl executed\n");
fwrite($fh, "curl info: ".print_r(curl_getinfo($ch,true))."\n");
fwrite($fh, "xml dump: $upload_result \n");
fwrite($fh, "curl error: ".curl_error($ch)."\n");
```

i also

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60*60);
```

Comment: Are any errors raised? Perhaps your script is exceeding it's time limit.

Comment: Do you have error reporting and error display or logging turned on? Have you used curl_getinfo() and curl_errmsg()?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what the issue is... What is in the response when it fails? What do the system and apache logs say?

Now if i were you i wouldnt use `curl_init()` and `curl_close()` in the loop. instead i would init before the loop, and close after the loop - then within the loop itsef i would use `curl_set_opt` to set the url and differing parameters and just call `curl_exec()`. It may even be its a matter of all these handles exceeding some kind of system limit or something. If you need/want to use multiple connections you could use `curl_multi` or write some management functions/class to manage multiple handles.

Comment: i dont have access to apache log. it just stopped.

Comment: @prodigitalson - I think you meant to say "...I wouldn't use curl_init() and curl_close() in the loop."

Comment: @Funky Dude: Then you need to turn on `display_errors` temporarily and also see if you can get the content of the response being handed back to you from curl. Without any info as to why its failing we are only guessing.

Comment: @prodigitalson: error display and reporting are on. it shows error before curl_exec. at the point where it fails, curl_exec just halts everything without displaying anything.

Answer (score 1):

We may need more info before we can help, but it sounds like it could be a timeout issue.

Turn on error reporting or check your error logs to see if anything is being raised.

Try setting a long cURL timeout with `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`

Also check that your script timeout is sufficient or increase with `set_time_limit()`

Answer (score 1):

1- Force Curl to tell you a bit more about what it does

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

2- If you are not in safe mode, make sure PHP displays errors by putting this at the beginning of your script:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

3- You can also try to run your script in CLI mode.

4- Finally, still if you are not in safe mode, you can try to directly run the curl binary using exec().

```
<?php

$curl_str = "curl -k -o /my/path/curl_output.log -d 'var1=".$value1."&var2=".$value2."& etc...' https://upload.smugmug.com/services/api/rest/1.2.2/";
$r = exec($curl_str);
```

Comment: Curl does not work in browser - Safari und Chrome, result from `$r=curl_exec($curl)` is `false`. It hangs, but I stop the hanging with `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);`. But from cli `php script.php` it works with true as result.

Answer (score 0):

You could try whether outputting [**curl_error()**](https://www.php.net/curl_error) directly works:

```
$upload_result = curl_exec($ch); //fails here

$error = curl_error($ch);    
if ($error) echo "CURL Error: $error";

curl_close($ch);
```

If that doesn't help, check your `phpinfo();` to see whether error reporting is turned off globally (look for the `display_errors` setting).

Answer (score 0):

CURL includes the 'multi' (for multiple-resources) options for when one is dealing with multiple high-latency requests (such as uploading images).

See:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php
and the entire library of 'multi' functions described here:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

For a complete example of the multiple resource section of the library, see:
http://www.developertutorials.com/blog/php/parallel-web-scraping-in-php-curl-multi-functions-375/

Answer (score 0):

I am using this ajax here below to call a function inside ajax.php file

```
$.ajax({
            url:'ajax.php?action=save_parcel',
            data: new FormData($(this)[0]),
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            method: 'POST',
            type: 'POST',
            success:function(resp){
             if(resp){
             resp = JSON.parse(resp)
        
        if(resp == 1){
            //var nw = window.open('print_pdets.php? 
        ids='+resp.ids,"_blank","height=700,width=900")
            alert_toast('Data successfully saved',"success");
            setTimeout(function(){
              location.href = 'index.php?page=parcel_list';
            },2000)

        }
        }
            }
        })
```

Below is the ajax.php -> action=save_parcel' being called from above
ajax:

```
<?php
ob_start();
date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Nairobi");

$action = $_GET['action'];
include 'admin_class.php';
$crud = new Action();

if($action == 'save_parcel'){
    $save = $crud->save_parcel();
    if($save)
        echo $save;
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Then from above, calls admin.php(save_parcel)function:

```
function save_parcel(){   
extract($_POST);
        
                $login_name=$_SESSION['login_name'];
                $agent_id=$_SESSION['login_id'];
                $data .= ", reference_number='$ref' ";
                $data .= ", created_by='$login_name' ";
                $data .= ", agent_id='$agent_id' ";
                if($save[] = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO parcels set 
                  $data"))
                    $ids[]= $this->db->insert_id;
                $message ="Dear" ." ".$recipient_name.",". "Your parcel reference No:"." ".$ref. " "."has been sent from"." ".Branch_name." "."We will notify you when your parcel arrives in"." ".To_branch.". "."Thank you for using K-Prestige shuttle. You may reach us anytime on 0733xxx/0722XXXX";
                
                
            $url = "http://localhost:8130/api/1/webconnection/1";

            //Initiate cURL.
            $ch = curl_init($url);
            
            //The JSON data.
             $jsonData = array( 
                                    'secret' => '123', 
                                    'message' => $message, 
                                    'recipients' => array(array( 
                                            'type' => 'address', 
                                            'value' => '07358688'
                                    ))
                            );
                    
            //Encode the array into JSON.
            $jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);
            

            //Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            //Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

            //Set the content type to application/json
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: 
            application/json')); 

            //Execute the request
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
              if(curl_errno($ch))
                {
                    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
                }

                curl_close($ch);
}
```

**Notes:**
Above is sending an sms message which it does fine but the application
cursor keeps rotating in an indefinite loop instead of going to
location.href = 'index.php?page=parcel_list'  as indicated above.